# apt-get upgrade fails becuse of unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, kali-linux, themes, apt-get, xfce

I've been kali linux for a while, but recently ive been unable to upgrade or install new software

when i run `apt-get update` , the list is updated successfully, but on running `apt-get upgrade` i get the following log

```
root@MrApollos:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kali-desktop-base : Depends: kali-themes-common (= 2021.2.3) but 2021.2.1 is installed
 kali-themes : Depends: kali-themes-common (= 2021.2.3) but 2021.2.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

why i try to run `apt --fix-broken install` as suggested above, i get this error

```
root@MrApollos:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kali-themes-common                                                                                                                                                   
Suggested packages:                                                                                                                                                    
  kali-wallpapers-2019.4 kali-wallpapers-legacy
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kali-themes-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,717 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 327594 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kali-themes-common_2021.2.3_all.deb ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/check-symbolic.svg' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/bullet-symbolic.svg' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/dash-symbolic.symbolic.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/kali-headerbar-logo.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-hover@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/kali-headerbar-logo-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/kali-headerbar-logo-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-hover.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-hover-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-active-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/kali-headerbar-logo@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-hover-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-end-active-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/dash-symbolic.svg' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-dark@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/text-select-start-active@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below-active.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-below-backdrop-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-below@2.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/bullet-symbolic.symbolic.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-horz-scale-has-marks-above-insensitive-dark.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/slider-vert-scale-has-marks-above-backdrop-insensitive.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets/check-symbolic.symbolic.png' not owned by package 'kali-themes-common:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/themes/Kali-Light/gtk-3.0/assets' contains files not owned by package kali-themes-common:all, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes-common_2021.2.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new kali-themes-common package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes-common_2021.2.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the problem persists even after trying `apt-get clean`, and it occurs each time i want to install a new package using `apt` or `dpkg -i <package>.deb`

my `sources.list` file is like so

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

I'm running xFce desktop

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
  I have used this successfully before.

Answer (score 2):

I did
`pkg --force-all --configure -a`
then i did
`dpkg --purge --force-depends <bad package>`
for each of the bad packages (`kali-desktop-base`, `kali-themes-common` and `kali-themes`)
then
`apt --fix-broken install`
and finally,
`apt-get -f install`